# Reversed IP localisation in python

Tags: python, ip

I have an old project in python : Get the IP corresponding to a location. I know we can get IP from a location (I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543018/what-python-libraries-can-tell-me-approximate-location-and-time-zone-given-an-ip)), and I would like to know if it's possible to reverse the process.

Here's the idea I had:

•Using the method given in the link, and a "for", to test a large range of IP until we get the wanted location. With some filters I hope we can reduce the amount of IP to test. => Long, and not very efficient

•Exploring the database given [here](http://www.hostip.info/dl/index.html), but I don't know how

Does it's possible ? If yes, what's the best solution for you ?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Given that there may be *millions* of IPs at any given "location", I'd first ask you to clarify what "the" IP is expected to be.

Comment: You'r Right. I would like to get the location  corresponding to a public ip (given [by this site](http://whatismyipaddress.com) for eg.). This site can give a location with the IP (for me 78.245.240.*** ) and it's accurate.

Comment: Now I'm confused. You want to get a location corresponding to an IP address? Or you want to get the *reverse*, the IP at a given location...?!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not english-native so... I mean the IP at a given location

Comment: So you give it something like "Sheffield, England" and you expect "1.2.3.4" as response...?

Comment: Yes, something like this

Comment: So, for many locations you'd get a list of some thousand IP addresses. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

There are [Python bindings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GeoIP/) for the [GeoIP](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/) library.

Also their databases are downloadable.

[Here](https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-python/tree/master/examples) there are some examples in Python. Your use case seems that is not covered. You may have to manually open and search their databases.